# Manipulating a GeoTIFF file

Tags: ios, objective-c, geotiff

I have a GeoTIFF image file in binary from our server:

retrieveTiffForImageHandle:] | tiff result: <49492a00 08000000 13000001 03000100 00002c00 00000101 03000100 00002d00 00000201 03000100 00000800 00000301 03000100 00000100 00000601 03000100 00000300 00000e01 02002c00 0000f206 00001101 04000100 00002a14 00001501 03000100 00000100

I need to be able to manipulate the pixel colors within the file. So say for a given pixel is green, I want to change that pixel to blue.

I tried googling a objective c tiff reader but came up empty. I tried looking over Apple's frameworks and can not seem to find any help there. NSImage for OSX seems like it could do what I need, but I don't see a iOS equivalent.

Any suggestions on where to start?